How to clear static layer obstacles in dynamic warehouse setups?
In a warehouse, static obstacles like boxes often change position or shape. The static costmap ends up outdated and creates problems for navigation. What’s the best way to keep the static layer updated?
I have tried:
Setting the combination_method = 0 in costmap while having SLAM and navigation running simultaneously. This way removes the inside of the obstacle but leaves the black border outside (as shown below). This still acts as a static obstacle and doesn’t fully clear it.
What has worked for you to keep static layer updated?

